# How to use function in Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I want filter a list of objects by property "innerText". But I need to do some preparations.
Why furhter code doesn't works? It returns all objects.

```
function enc[[string]$inp]
{
    return [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($inp))
}

$req.Links | Where-Object { enc($_.innerText) -eq "my string"} | fl
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Unfortunately I didn't find the necessary article in the Internet.
There are a lot of such examples: ($_.Name -eq "name") - and nothing valueable for me.

Comment: Powershell functions (and CmdLets) must be named in form `Verb-Noun`.  Please see [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx). Unless you do so, you will find out that in some situations it will fill your output with warnings.

Comment: That's only if you're providing a module, so all commands follow the same standard and are easy to find. For a simple function in a script etc. you could call it whatever you want (try to avoid names that are already taken).

Comment: @FrodeF thanks. I will note it. I started studying powershell recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is how you defined your function.

```
function enc
{
    param ([string]$inp)

    return [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($inp))
}

$req.Links | Where-Object { (enc $_.innerText) -eq "my string"} | fl
```

Simple test:

```
$a = "hello","world"
function enc
{
    param ([string]$inp)
    $inp
}

$a | Where-Object { (enc $_) -eq "hello"}
```

Comment: I suggets adding brackets - 
`$(enc $_.innerText) -eq "my string"`
To keep safe from undefined behavior

Comment: or `function enc([string]$inp) { ... }`

Comment: Great! Thanks. Function's definition is ok, but instead of my  `enc($_.innerText)`, should be yours `(enc $_.innerText)`. Like @filimonic noticed